# "the xxx section OF the yyy document" or "the xxx section IN the yyy document"

Tags: prepositions, in-of

Today in a book I read a sentence similar to this:

> The "Conversions" section **in** the language specification.

Although before I have read this, I would most likely said:

> The "Conversions" section **of** the language specification.

Is the second sentence correct? Can the both (IN / OF) be used interchangeably in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go ahead and say that in/of can be used interchangeably in this context.

Generally 'in' is the preposition of place/location and 'of' is the preposition of possession

In this case

"The "Conversions" section **in** the language specification." - place/location/position of "Conversions"

"The "Conversions" section **of** the language specification." - "Conversions" section belonging to "language specification"

Both of them sound about right.

But this is not the case usually, 'in' and 'of' are not interchangeable always. If you are interested to explore more about situations  using 'in' and 'of' interchangeably, refer to [this stack question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110928/prepositions-in-or-of-for-referring-to-a-population-of-a-country), am sure it will help you a bit more on understanding the notion.

Answer (score 2):

As far as a **document or book** is concerned, I'd use them in following way. (Note that this is what I feel and it's opinion based and may not be grammatically sound. This as a comment could have been lengthy and thus I'm posting it as an answer.)

I'd use *in* if it's a part of a topic or chapter. For instance,

> The last section *in* chapter 3 is jaw-dropping. You just cannot imagine the end.

I'd use *of* if it's a part of the book itself. For instance,

> The last chapter *of* the book is a bit boring.

So, in your question, *... section **in** the document* seems a preferred choice.